# Get brower network requests with Selenium for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium with chromeDriver for JavaScript and I want to get all network logs from the Browser with their payload.
I searched a lot but, there are ways to get the requests, but only the URL and not the payload.
The Chrome Devtools are able to record and track the requests in all of their details, why is there no simple way to do it in JavaScript?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: seems not possible, either use puppeteer or proxy (pass proxy config to webdriver).

Answer (score 1):

maybe this one will help your case https://github.com/dipansaha/BrowserMobNodeSelenium

but if you want to look an alternative , you can use puppeteer there is avaliable function to get request and response url